# Everything crashed after install lib in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, crash

Sorry for bothering,

I am running Django 3.0.1

```
$ python -m django --version
3.0.1
```

After installed:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/jhuapl-boss/boss-oidc.git
```

Django was uninstalled automatically without asking (django 3.0.1 is not supported with that lib, I noted that late)

First question: If I do a mistake installing no compatible libs the whole framework is uninstalled?

So, I reinstalled django 3.0.1, uninstalled the boss-oidc lib, actually python too from scratch, virtualenv, and who knows what else.

So, from that moment, after I apply makemigrations, nothing works.

I tried cloning a github repo, going to a old commit, it does not work (at the end the log).

If I create a new empty project and add some models, it does the migrations without problems.

I am new in Django, I would like to know if this is so unstable or It is just me learning from scratch.

I can not recover my whole work from the last 20 days.

The log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/mariano/Code/Python/Django3.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/mariano/Code/Python/Django3.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/mariano/Code/Python/Django3.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/Users/mariano/Code/Python/Django3.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 230, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "/Users/mariano/Code/Python/Django3.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mariano/Code/Python/Django3.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 261, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "/Users/mariano/Code/Python/Django3.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 380, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "/Users/mariano/Code/Python/Django3.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
```

I was some hours working on it, sorry for bothering you with this question but with the pandemic isolation thing, my head is going to crash.

```
...

from pathlib import Path

...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

...
```

Comment: show us your DATABASES settings

Comment: I read it, I will read it again. Both are using pathlib. I am running code uploaded to git. It was working.

Comment: iklinac thank you so much, It is working with the casting, but it was working before without it. Why? I had to import os too now... The behavior changed after the lib installation and uninstalling everything from scratch. Why? Which files has been modified ? Thank you once again.

Comment: Resolved. I was using 3.1. Reinstalling I confused 3.0.1 with 3.1.